# Error on Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

> Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Message: T-SQL ERROR
>   242, SEVERITY 16, STATE 3, PROCEDURE (null), LINE 472, MESSAGE: The
>   conversion of a datetime data type to a smalldatetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. Source: .Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderTransaction.Dispose()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__2()
>   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.ExecuteNoResult(Action
>   action, Action recover)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.Store(Guid
>   id, AggregationDataSet data)    at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Platform.SwitchingReportingStorageProvider.Store(Guid
>   id, AggregationDataSet data)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.InteractionAggregator.Aggregate(Byte[]
>   recordKey, IAggregationContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Aggregator.Execute()

What is the possible cause of the error. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about your system? Did you recently upgrade? ...

Comment: NO Update. I saw this error only. No other error. Is this error coming from analytic database???

Comment: Have you looked into https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/282795 ?